# RStudio View() a list of lists with repeated names gives different visual result from Environment

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently spotted something weird with RStudio, see codes that can replicate the issue below

```
test_list <- list()
test01 <- list(a = list(a1 = 1), b = list(b1 = 2, b2 =3))
test02 <- list(a = list(a3 = 4444), b = list(b2 =9999))
test_list <- c(test01, test02)
View(test_list)
```

If reviewing from the `Environment`, numbers seem correct.
[image: see list in Enviroment]

However if reviewing with View(), I got [image: result weirdly displayed]

I have submitted a issue here https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12936 but could someone explain what's going on here before rstudio team could have some time to view the backlogs?

Comment: That is certainly unique to the RStudio IDE, and it might indeed be a bug. Is this a problem with a real dataset? R is never a fan of a named-list with duplicate names; it is allowed (obviously) but indexing on the names is not necessarily consistent, and I don't have any use-cases in my mind where same-named elements would be a good thing.

Comment: Hi @r2evans it's not a real dataset, but the codes to reproduce the issue has been posted.